# Does Flutter support Platform specific files?

Tags: flutter, platform

**Does Flutter support Platform specific files?**
Can we have platform specific files created – say *myButton.dart* as *myButton.iOS.dart* and *myButton.android.dart* so that when myButton file is imported, it picks up appropriate file based on platform and executes it.

Comment: use platform specific widgets with an if statement like that Platform.isIOS / Platform.isAndroid

Answer (score 0):

No there is built in solution like you described, you can however just write a thin wrapper widget, which chooses the correct widget based on the platform:

```dart
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return MyIOSButton();
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return MyAndroidButton();
    } else
      return GenericButton();
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you want to have some premade widget, you can look at the [flutter_platform_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets) package.

Which already provides a generic widgets, to make platform aware widgets:

```dart
return PlatformWidget(
  ios: (_) => Icon(CupertinoIcons.flag),
  android: (_) => Icon(Icons.flag),
);
```